# Looking for foreign keys in a DataSet

Tags: c#, dataset, database-relations

Is there a way to look for all of the `foreign keys` in a data set?

I know there's a way to look for all of the relations:

```
new DataSet().Relations
```

Is there a similar `proptery` for just `foreign keys`?

Comment: If a relation is not a foreign key, then what is it?

Comment: @MD.Unicorn: It looks like you can make a `foreign key` without it being a `relation`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [`foreignkeyconstraint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.foreignkeyconstraint.aspx) Class, so for each `DataTable` in your dataset you can find the list of its [`Constraints`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.constraints.aspx), which will give you all constraints including any foreign keys of type `foreignkeyconstraint`.